# How can I make these two index-locating filters into one generic one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

I have two filters, `findEdited` and `getUnitIndex`. They both do exactly the same thing (find the index of an element in an array), but in different parts of an array. I would like to combine them into one filter, `getIndex`.

Here's the first one:

```
myApp.filter('findEdited', function(){
  return function(food, foods) {
    for (var index in foods) {
      if (foods[index].uid == food.uid) {
        return index;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
});
```

In the controller:

```
var index = $filter('findEdited')(food, $scope.editedFood);
```

And the second one:

```
myApp.filter('getUnitIndex', function () {
  return function(list, item) {
        for( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
            if( list[i].gram == item.gram ) {
                return(i);
            }
        }
        return(-1);
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
var unitIndex = $filter('getUnitIndex')(food.unit, $scope.editedFood[index].unit.selected);
```

As near as I can tell, the only functional difference between them is the .uid & .gram identifier, which is telling the loop which part of the object to match. I've tried to rewrite these into one filter, like this, with `ref` standing in for this identifier:

```
myApp.filter('findIndex', function () {
return function(list, item, ref) {
    for( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
        if( list[i].ref == item.ref ) {
            return(i);
        }
    }
    return(-1);
  }
});
```

And called like this, if I want `ref` to be uid:

```
var unitIndex = $filter('findIndex')(food.unit, $scope.editedFood[index].unit.selected, 'uid');
```

This doesn't work. The example above returns 0 on every run. Any suggestions on how to pass the desired reference to this filter so that I can use it generically to find the index of any array item in any array?

## [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1VCfHLp4NXSEZm9C1kk2?p=preview)

---

## Update

I can't get this to work for the filter "findEdited". I have written my generic filter like this:

```
myApp.filter('getIndex', function(){
    return function(list, item, ref) {
    for (var index in list) {
          if (list[index][ref] == item[ref]) {
        return index;
      }
     }
    return -1;
  }
});
```

Which works if call it like this, to find the index of a food unit by matching 'gram':

```
var unitIndex = $filter('getIndex')(food.unit, $scope.editedFood[index].unit.selected, 'gram');
```

But it doesn't work if I call it like this, to find out if a food unit exists in the array editedFood:

```
var foodIndex = $filter('getIndex')(food, $scope.editedFood, 'uid');
```

I can see that I am passing in different search objects & search contexts, but the foodIndex search works if I pass it to the almost-identical filter `findEdited` filter above. Any ideas why?

## [Here's an updated Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/OEWf6B6vRjQEa0oDBRLV?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You must use the array-like notation here (you can use it for objects as well). `item.ref` would mean the property called `ref`, while `item[ref]` will mean the property called whatever the expression in the `[]` evaluates to (in this case, whatever is stored in the variable called `ref`).

```
if( list[i][ref] == item[ref] ) {
```

In other words, writing `item.ref` is equivalent to writing `item['ref']`.